# Does "subtractivity" hold from the property of additivity on the general lebesgue functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

I know that a few key properties hold on general Lebesgue functions, including additivity: for disjoint subsets $E_1, E_2$ of $\mathbb{R}$ we have that

$\int_{E_1 \cup E_2} f = \int_{E_1} f + \int_{E_2} f$

Suppose instead we have that, WLOG, $E_1 \subseteq E_2$.

Can it be said that the following is true:

$\int_{E_1 - E_2} f = \int_{E_1} f - \int_{E_2} f$

Is this trivial? What would be the best approach of proving this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should assume that $E_1,E_2$ are Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $E_1\supset E_2$. With this, we have
$$E_1-E_2=E_1\cap E_2^c$$
which is a measurable set, and $E_1$ can be written as a union of disjoint measurable sets:
$$E_1=E_2\cup(E_1-E_2).$$
It follows that
$$\int_{E_1}f=\int_{E_2}f+\int_{E_1-E_2}f.$$
This shows the claim.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but this yields $\int_{E_2}f=0$ if $E_1=\{\}$, no? I think $E_1=E_2\cup(E_1\setminus E_2)$ is wrong.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Here we assume that $E_1\supseteq E_2$. I add that to my answer.